# Block the download of images on Selenium headless Chrome [python]

Tags: python, image, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The following two python codes block the download of images on selenium non-headless chrome, ie in the saved screenshots the images are not visible. If we uncomment the two commented lines the codes don't work anymore as expected though, that is images are visible in the screenshots saved by the headless chrome browser. How to properly block images from loading in the headless chrome on selenium for python?

First method

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.default_content_settings.images": 2})
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"profile.managed_default_content_settings.images": 2})
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options, executable_path = ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://www.hdblog.it/page/1/')
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

second method

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_prefs = {}
option.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
# option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=option, executable_path = ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get('https://www.hdblog.it/page/1/')
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

preference is not supported for headless browser

As of Feb , 2021

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1925

Headless chrome doesn't support preferrences setting . You can use command line arguments only.

the full list of supported arguments are :

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Here you can see --blink-settings so ,

try

```
chrome_options.add_arguments('--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
```

full blink settings can be accessed here :

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/frame/Settings.in

Comment: thank you it works! do you know if with this method images are still downloaded and then hidden or if rather the download of the images is totally blocked?

Comment: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/frame/Settings.in read about imagesEnabled

Comment: There is another blink option download automatic or something you can try that also